# How can I add a Gesture Recognizer to a series of subviews?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I have a grid of subview images that are display on the screen; it's basically a series of images laid out on the screen in checker board manner. I simply want add gesture recognizers to each one of those image- subviews so that when the user touches one of the images subviews, I can retrieve the subview i.e. the coordinates, tag, etc. My view hierarchy goes like this:

1. The super view
2. A gridContainer view
3. and each individual subview - with image

After looking at the apple documentation it seems as though I should be able to add a gesture recognizer to the gridContainer view and each one of the subviews - with images - should inherit the gesture recognizer. So far this is what I've tried: I've alloc'ed init'ed the grid container view in the getter. Also, in the getter I called my createGesture method which is supposed to add a gesture recognizer to the gridContainer view. However I'm getting an error at runtime that's pointing to my action handleSingleTap method. It reads EXC_BAD_EXCESS.
It's also worth noting that I don't want the view outside of my gridContainer view to respond to any touch event. Thanks in advance for any help.

Here is the code I'm trying to implement:

```
- (UIView *)gridContainerView
{
    if (!_gridContainerView)_gridContainerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [self createGesture];
    return _gridContainerView;
}
- (void)createGesture
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                         initWithTarget:self.gridContainerView
                                         action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

    [self.gridContainerView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
}
```

If you need to see any additional code for this to make sense, please let me know.

Edit: including the handleSingleTap method:

```
- (IBAction)handleSingleTap:(id)sender
{
    CGPoint tapPoint = [sender locationInView:sender];
    NSLog(@"sender = %@",sender);
    NSLog(@"tappoint = %@", tapPoint);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are initializing a plain `UIView` for your gridContainerView. Then you attach a gesture recognizer to it (using that view instance as the target). A plain `UIView` however does not implement `handleSingleTap:`, hence you get an exception.

You should create a (custom `UIView` derived) class that implements the selector you need that gesture to trigger.

Comment: So I should create a custom class that's a subview of UIView? Should I push my gridContainerView into this custom class, and then just call it in my controller when I need access it?

Comment: Not a subview but a subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Several problems right off the bat (without even dealing with handling your gesture).

You will be calling createGesture every single time you access the gridContainerView.  You probably only want this to happen when you create the view.  Additionally, if you look at createGesture, it calls back into gridContainerView, which calls back into createGesture, which calls back into gridContainerView, etc.

You probably want something more like...

```
- (UIView *)gridContainerView
{
    if (!_gridContainerView) {
        _gridContainerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [self createGesture];
    }
    return _gridContainerView;
}
```

Next, you are trying to call handleSingleTap on the view.  You probably want it on the controller: initWithTarget:self.

```
- (void)createGesture
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                         initWithTarget:self
                                         action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

    [self.gridContainerView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
}
```

You probably want to retying the wisdom of having two separate methods that directly reference each other like this.  However, at least with the change we made to the accessor, it should be OK.  Just know that, if you add more code in the accessor, the view has to be completely setup before you call createGesture.

Comment: Those are some good points, however my handleSingleTap method dosen't seem to be responding to touch events. I edited my code above and included the handle single tap method. Any idea s to why it's not responding?

Answer (score 0):

A couple things.  First, you're instantiating the gridContainerView as a standard UIView and then sending it the message: handleSingleTap:, which it most certainly doesn't respond to.  If you want your gridContainerView to respond to the message, you'll need to subclass UIView, create the appropriate method, and instantiate your gridContainerView as the subclass.

Second, as for an overall approach, I would create the subclass for gridContainerView (maybe even call it that) and create the method to handle the gesture.  In that method, you can get access to the point that was touched/tapped by using the UIGestureRecognizer method `locationInView:`.  Use this point to determine which subview in the gridContainerView was tapped and perform the appropriate actions.  To discover which subview was tapped, you can iterate through your subviews and check the each one to determine which one contains the point that was tapped.  There are several methods UIView has that you can use to do this:

`pointInside:withEvent:`
`hitTest:withEvent:`

Note, you can pass `nil` for the event.  The above two things do slightly different things.  If you're just testing whether the point is located in the view, use `pointInside:withEvent` as it will return a `BOOL`.  The method `hitTest:withEvent` will cause the view to search all of its subviews and return either itself or one of its subviews (or nil if the point is outside it's bounds).  `hitTest:withEvent` can be a little more processor intensive.  Also, you can just use `CGRectContainsPoint()` to test as well.